# Catch errors and log in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have big script with many INSERT operations. Some of them maybe have mistakes, so I want to write them into a temp table.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

I would use something like a [try catch block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) with SQL 2005

Example quoted from the site:

```
BEGIN TRY
    -- Generate a divide-by-zero error.
    SELECT 1/0;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
        ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
        ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState,
        ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,
        ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,
        ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
END CATCH;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Server 2005 XML Support, Exception Handling, and More](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163611.aspx)

[MSDN Webcast: T-SQL Exception Handling in SQL Server 2005 (Level 200)](https://msevents.microsoft.com/cui/WebCastEventDetails.aspx?culture=en-US&EventID=1032284325&CountryCode=US)